# Define field type from template class's field type, instead of adding extra class on the template

Tags: c++

I have a generic caching class (the example is simplified from what I have in my code base). The items are stored in a map, and the template type T should have a field `id` so that I can store it in a map.

```c
struct Car
{
  int id;
  std::string name;
};

struct Aeroplane
{
  std::string id;
  int top_speed;
  std::string brand;
};

template<class T, class S>
class Cache
{
public:
  void Add(T item)
  {
    cache.emplace(item.id, item);    
  }

  bool Contains(T item)
  {
    return cache.find(item.id) != cache.end();
  }

private:
  map<S, T> cache;
};

int main()
{
  Cache<Car, int> cars;
  // we can add Car instances to cars here

  Cache<Aeroplane, std::string> aeroplanes;
  // we can add Aeroplane instances to aeroplanes here

}
```

For now is the class S can be anything but it must be the same type as T.id.
It would be very nice if we can say that cache should be a map from the type of T.id to T. Then I can simplify the templating by removing class S.

```c
template<class T>
class Cache
{
public:
  ... should be same as above ...

private:
  // is it possible?
  map< /* the type of T.id ??? */ , T> cache;
};

int main()
{
  // it would be very nice if we can simplify it, so that the definition looks like this
  Cache<Car> cars;

  // and...
  Cache<Aeroplane> aeroplanes;
}
```

Does anybody know how do I do this?

Comment: `decltype(T::id)`?

Comment: Pre C++11, you might force the class to have a typedef: `typedef int id_type;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a default for `S` like this:

```
template<class T, class S = decltype(std::declval<T>().id)>
class Cache
{
public:
  void Add(T item)
  {
    cache.emplace(item.id, item);    
  }

  bool Contains(T item)
  {
    return cache.find(item.id) != cache.end();
  }

private:
  map<S, T> cache;
};

int main()
{
  Cache<Car> cars;
  // we can add Car instances to cars here

  Cache<Aeroplane> aeroplanes;
  // we can add Aeroplane instances to aeroplanes here

}
```

Or get rid of it the second template parameter, like this:

```
template<class T>
class Cache
{
public:
  using S = decltype(std::declval<T>().id);
  // ...
  map<S, T> cache;
};
```

Or shorter (thanks to @MikeVine):

```
template<class T>
class Cache
{
public:
  using S = decltype(T::id);
  // ...
  map<S, T> cache;
};
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `decltype(std::declval<T>().id)` over `decltype(T::id)`?

Comment: @MikeVine none. The difference between the two is that I wasnt aware that `decltype(T::id)` compiles ;) I'll add it to the answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm running it with g++ and the first and second options are perfectly fine. My g++ doesn't like the third one. But this is good enough for me. Thanks.

Comment: Having no problem compiling all of the options with g++ with language version c++17.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to get the type of an expression. And the expression will not actually be executed, just evaluated in terms of type.

So you could do something like

```
template<class T, class S = decltype(T().id)>
class Cache
{
    ...
}
```

This will make sure that `S` is the same type as whatever `id` is in an instance of `T`.